# Printar ou desenhar widget com flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Eu tenho o seguinte dialog e gostaria de gerar um "comprovante" para que a pessoa pudesse compartilha-lo, como se fosse comprovante de pagamentos que os aplicativos de bancos geram. 
[image: dialog para gerar comprovante]

Consegui tirar um "print" utilizando RenderRepaintBundary, com o código abaixo, porem ele fica com uma resolução horrível e com os textos bem desproporcionais.

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject(); 
  var image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 5.0);
  ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
  Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();       
  final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final file = await new File('${tempDir.path}/image.png').create();
  await file.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
  final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(file.path);
  await Share.file('Invite', 'qrcode.png', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png', text: 'Convite para entrada no meu condomínio');
```

Answer (score -1):

Blz? já se faz um tempo desde a pergunta, mas creio q a resposta seja válida futuramente

basta adicionar o parâmetro *pixelRatio* no boundary.toImage

```
Future<void> _capturePng() async {
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
    _globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

await Share.file('ESYS AMLOG', 'amlog.jpg', pngBytes, 'image/jpg');}
```